# Distances in the space of probability measures and couplings of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, total-variation, coupling

**One-sentence summary:** I want an intuitive explanation for why closeness of probability measures (in terms of, eg., TV or Lévy-Prokhorov) implies the existence of good couplings.

**Set up.** Consider a separable metric space $(X,d)$ and the space of probability measures $\mathcal{M}(X)$. Equip $\mathcal{M}(X)$ with one of the "usual" metrics $\rho$: for the concreteness of this post let's consider $\rho$ to be [Lévy-Prokhorov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric) or [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) (TVD) (it is a theorem that $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is separable under either of these metrics).

It is a theorem that, if $\mu_1, \mu_2 \in \mathcal{M}(X)$ satisfy $\rho(\mu_1, \mu_2) <\epsilon$ for one of these choices of $\rho$, then there exists a "good" coupling: i.e., there exists a measure $\mu$ on $X\times X$ such that the random variables $(Y, Z) \sim \mu$ satisfy

1. $Y \sim \mu_1$ and $Z \sim \mu_2$, and
2. $d(Y,Z) < \epsilon$ with $\mu$-probability $> 1-\epsilon$.
   (I know we have an even stronger statement when $\rho$ is taken to be TVD, but that's not the point of this post-- this one is enough for me)
   (Ref: Billingsley, Convergence of Probability Measures, Theorem 6.9)

**The Question.** Is there an intuitive way to understand this theorem, or more generally the relation between these distances on spaces of probability measures (which seems abstract to me) and good/optimal couplings (which seems concrete to me)? EDIT: maybe some kind of theorem that says closeness of the laws "projects down" to closeness of the random variables?

I have taken a look at the proofs of the above result and the famous Coupling Lemma (for TVD), but both proofs are rather opaque to me--- they feel like a bit of abstract nonsense, but I am hoping that I do not have the right understanding.

Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be a detour: I would recommend to try to better digest the coupling argument for the total variation distance instead of trying to substitute it by something more abstract if the goal is to gain intuition.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking at these proofs in the setting of a general measure space? I think the proof of the TVD version in the case of finite sets, so a probability distribution is just a function valued in the nonnegative reals that sums to one, is very clear. The abstraction may be more related to the technicalities needed to handle an arbitrary measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some kind of projection theorem, that lets us deduce closeness of random variables from closeness of their laws?

Certainly not. Two random variables can have the same law but be highly distant as random variables.

However it's certainly true that we can go the other way: If two random variables are close in some sense then their laws are close. In both the examples you're thinking of this is easy to see.

The converse of "If two random variables are close then their laws are close" is not true, but "If two random variables are close then their laws are close" implies that "If there exists a coupling of two distributions by two random variables that are close, then their laws are close", and that weaker statement does have a true converse.

But the crucial part of proving the converse is *finding* a coupling that makes the random variable close. This requires some construction of a coupling.

I think this construction is the part you find to be abstract nonsense? But while there could possibly be many different sorts of constructions, there isn't going to be an explanation without some kind of construction (or related abstract argument), since the hard part of the statement is the existence of something.

Comment: Loved the answer, thank you! I really appreciated framing the coupling result in terms of its converse (which makes the result seem much more natural), as well as the point that existence results are generally proven abstractly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure my post will answer your question. A distance on a space of probability measures can sometimes be written as the minimal metric with respect to a probability metric. A probability metric $\beta$ is similar to a distance on the space of random variables taking their values in a separable metric space: it satisfies symmetry, the triangle inequality, and the property $P(X=Y)=1 \implies \beta(X,Y) = 0$. Given a probability metric $\beta$ one associates the distance between two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ by $$\rho(\mu,\nu) = \inf \{\beta(X,Y) \mid X\sim \mu, Y \sim \nu\}.$$ This is the minimal metric with respect to $\beta$. An example of probability metric is the Ky Fan metric $$\alpha(X,Y) = \inf\{\epsilon>0 \mid P(d(X,Y)>\epsilon) < \epsilon\}.$$ Then the Lévy-Prokhorov distance is the minimal metric with respect to $\alpha$. See [these slides](https://methods.stat.kit.edu/download/doc_secure1/3_StochModels.pdf) and [this article](http://www.math.bas.bg/%7Epliska/Pliska-07/Pliska-07-1984-152-162.pdf) for some information about minimal metrics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is helpful to think that the metric between two measures is defined in terms of the metric between (couplings of) the random variables. But the question is really: "why" can the Levy-Prokhorov distance be expressed as the minimal metric wrt Ky-Fan? Is there some kind of projection theorem, that lets us deduce closeness of random variables from closeness of their laws?